# DateTimeException while using DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.FULL) with LocalTime instance

Tags: java, java-8, datetime-format, date

In Java 8 Date Time API, I am going to print time using `DateTimeFormatter` API like following:

```
DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.FULL);
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(12, 45, 0);
System.out.println(timeFormatter.format(time));
```

`FormatStyle.FULL` - this format style works well with `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` instance. But throwing an exception with `LocalTime` instance:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract value: class java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext$1
```

According to doc:

```
public enum FormatStyle {
    // ordered from large to small

    /**
     * Full text style, with the most detail.
     * For example, the format might be 'Tuesday, April 12, 1952 AD' or '3:30:42pm PST'.
     */
    FULL,
```

Why is exception throwing?

Comment: @Marvin, Please note that I have taken a `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime` which is legal to use with a `LocalTime` instance. Question is doesn't `FormatStyle.FULL` format style work with `LocalTime` instance? Please explain in case anything I got wrong.

Comment: I get exceptions with `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate` as well. Might indeed be a bug in the JDK.

Comment: With `FormatStyle.FULL`, I am getting exception for `LocalTime` and `LocalDateTime`. Maybe it's for the same reason. Because in `LocalDateTime` there is a `LocalTime`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like you are getting hit by [JDK-JDK-8085887: java.time.format.FormatStyle.LONG or FULL causes unchecked exception](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8085887) (fixed in JDK 9).

The reason behind the exception is stated in the first comment there:

> Printing a time nearly always requires the timezone to be known and available. 
>   The LocalDateTime does not have a field or value for the timezone.

The comment also states that this is locale dependend due to different patterns, but that's probably not relevant for your case. I'll include it for reference, though:

> The program shows different behaviors in different locales because the locale specific pattern selected may or may not include a pattern letter than prints the timezone or zone offset. Those patterns including the letters: V, z, O, X, or, x require a timezone.

When looking at the diff (e.g. in [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rriggs/webrev-format-8085887/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.java.udiff.html)) you can see that they merely updated the javadoc to reflect that (with some additional improvements to the exception messages):

```
@@ -617,10 +617,13 @@
      * looking up the pattern required on demand.
      * <p>
      * The returned formatter has a chronology of ISO set to ensure dates in
      * other calendar systems are correctly converted.
      * It has no override zone and uses the {@link ResolverStyle#SMART SMART} resolver style.
+     * The {@code FULL} and {@code LONG} styles typically require a time-zone.
+     * When formatting using these styles, a {@code ZoneId} must be available,
+     * either by using {@code ZonedDateTime} or {@link DateTimeFormatter#withZone}.
      *
      * @param timeStyle  the formatter style to obtain, not null
      * @return the time formatter, not null
      */
     public static DateTimeFormatter ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle timeStyle) {
```

If you add a time zone to your `DateTimeFormatter` instance it works without exception:

```
DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter      
                                      .ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.FULL)
                                      .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(12, 45, 0);
System.out.println(timeFormatter.format(time));
```

Comment: Right you are. I astonished why my java doc differs to your one. In my java doc, there is nothing like: `Zone Id must be available`

Comment: That was fixed for JDK 9 only.

Comment: This is confusing.. I read in this timestamp via text file using `LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy HH:mm:ss:SSS z"));`. i.e., the original text string contained a zone. Did the parser, even though it was already told the zone, not create a `LocalDateTime` with a zone? And now my application must assert / hard-code a zone on the client's behalf? Hoping that if I serialize the LocalDateTime with the current user's `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, that will be correct for future consumers who deserialize it?

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` does not store time-zone information by design. If you always require a time-zone then maybe a _local_ date time is not the correct class to use?